# java.io.File.lastModified for a link, get the lastModified of the link file, instead of the linked file

Tags: java

```
$ touch file1.txt; sleep 60; ln -s file1.txt file2.txt; ls -l
$ -rw-r--r--   1 david  staff    0 Mar 29 22:58 file1.txt
$ lrwxr-xr-x   1 david  staff    9 Mar 29 22:59 file2.txt -> file1.txt
```

however, these two statements return the timestamp of file1.txt:

```
new java.io.File("file1.txt").lastModified()  // Mar 29 22:58
new java.io.File("file2.txt").lastModified()  // Mar 29 22:58
```

so, `file2.txt` is getting the `lastModified` info from its linked file.

same issue with `java.nio.file.Files`:

```
Files.readAttributes(new java.io.File("file2.txt").toPath(), classOf[PosixFileAttributes]).lastModifiedTime.toMillis
```

so, in Java/Scala, when I have a file which is a link, how can I get the `lastModifiedTime` (and `Files.readAttributes.permissions`) of the link file itself (instead of the linked file), as in the `ls -l` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javadoc for `java.nio.file.Files`:

> ```
> public static FileTime getLastModifiedTime(Path path,
>                                        LinkOption... options)
>                                 throws IOException
> ```
>
> Returns a file's last modified time.
>
> The options array may be used to indicate how symbolic links are handled for the case that the file is a symbolic link. By default, symbolic links are followed and the file attribute of the final target of the link is read. If the option NOFOLLOW_LINKS is present then symbolic links are not followed.